# How to disable "select all" in a WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox

On mouseclick on a WPF TextBox, the textbox gets the focus and selects all the text.

How I can this disable this behavior? On click only the caret shall be positioned on the char (as in good old windows).
Why? If I click on a textbox i want to mark some text, or set the carret position, to type more text. I do not want to deselect the whole marked text first and then click on the position again.

Another thing is, when the window lost the focus and get it back, the whole text is selected again and the carret position is lost. So it is not possible to copy text from another window and paste to the textbox w/o to select the correct carret position again.

Maybe this is a system "feature" (W8.1/W10) because non WPF textboxes have the same behavior, but this is annoying. Thanks for your helping ideas.

Answer (score 2):

My text box does not do this by default, The only one thing what i have done with it just bind TextBox.Text property with my ViewModel's property

Here described  the mechanism of things that you have mentioned above, you just need to revert them
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/564b5731-af8a-49bf-b297-6d179615819f/how-to-selectall-in-textbox-when-textbox-gets-focus-by-mouse-click?forum=wpf

Comment: the links shows how to "selected" all, but I do want to prevent from "select all". At present there is no logic and no binding on my textbox and always, the whole text ist selected.